# Creating several headers for accordion inside the loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops

I want to create several headers for accordion inside loop. There are can be different amount of processes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".Accordion").accordion({heightStyle:"content", collapsible:true});
});
<script>
<?php
for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++) {
    $result3 = getProcessNumber($projectNo, $holdprocess[$y]);
    if (!$result3) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
        $assigned =  $row3['assigned'] ;
    }
    ?>
    <div class='Accordion'>
        <h3>Process <?php echo $holdprocess[$y] ?> </h3>
        <div class='proc'>
            <div class='name'>Process: <?php echo $holdprocess[$y] ?>
                <div class='nmbr'>People required: <div class='numbr'><?php echo $holdnumber[$y] ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='assigned' name='assigned[]' >People Assigned:  <?php echo $assigned ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php   
}
?>
```

But it creates header only for last process. [image]

Comment: tag php and not jquery

Comment: Tag php and loops

Comment: I think the concept right and it will work fine. I can't get what you was expecting. If the SQL query you trying to fetch is right then the process is completely correct. First check the data you were fetching from database

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran there is should be same line for first line process as under second header. Please see edited question, i put all inside for loop. Output is still the same

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy what happens if you move the html block inside while loop block

Comment: @Parvez same. I think I found the problem. It looks weird because of the `div` elements. if I remove all `div` elements inside accordion and put some random text it works fine.

Comment: What did you changed @YevgeniyBagackiy